# How to overwrite cell function with Paste value only using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a database that makes live calculations, but once the new data added to the database has been processed that day, I effectively want to Copy + Paste value only on these cells so that the results of the formulas are fixed and can no longer change.

The current script I am using is:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getRange(1,2,ss.getLastRow());
  var vals = r.getValues();
  for(var i =0;i<vals.length;i++){
      ss.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(ss.getRange(i+1,2).getValue());
  }
}
```

However, in column B beneath the data set, all the cells start with IF(B2092="","",etc). On cells that are empty, I still require the formula to remain in place. I only want to script to be applied to cells that have data within.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
    var rg = ss.getRange(1,2,ss.getLastRow());

    var vals     = rg.getValues();   // get values
    var formulas = rg.getFormulas(); // get formulas

    // merge values & formulas
    var data = formulas.map((row,row_index) => 
                    row.map((cel, cel_index) => 
        { return (cel) ? cel : vals[row_index][cel_index] }));    

    rg.setFormulas(data);            // output
}
```

Corrected version:

```
function copy_values_and_formulas() {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
    var rg = ss.getRange(1,2,ss.getLastRow());
    
    var vals     = rg.getValues();   // get values
    var formulas = rg.getFormulas(); // get formulas
    
    // merge values & formulas
    var data = vals.map((row, row_index) => 
                row.map((cel, cel_index) => 
        { return (cel == 0) ? formulas[row_index][cel_index] : cel }));

    rg.setFormulas(data);            // output
}
```

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem to change anything on the sheet. You can see my example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LA4_NeNYjT5-LtfcuNL7ssSvScHEaFAa98-QKv88jco/edit#gid=0 The list on the left is how it will be displayed before the script is run. The table on the right is the results after >>> any cell with a result will 'fix' whilst the cells without a result will remain showing the formula. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a kinda brute-force since your link says 'Access Denied' (it makes sense to use public links). I've changed the line `var = data ...`, hope it helps. Try it again.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for you help :)

Comment: I have had this code work successfully, but the majority of the time I receive the error `Exceeded maximum execution time`. I wondered whether it is because the dataset is too large (10 columns and just over 3200 rows), so I changed the getRange to `var rg = ss.getRange(3100,12,ss.getLastRow(),10);` so that the script works from a smaller range from row 3100, however this hasn't sorted the issue. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can tell you done all right. GAS has the limits: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas  It looks as though you have exceeded some of those limits. Yep, 100 rows x 10 columns doesn't look exactly like The Big Data. But I'd try to process 50 or 10 rows just to see how it goes. And if it goes well, you can do a loop and to process all the data in a few steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = ss.getRange(1,2,ss.getLastRow());
  var vals = rg.getDisplayValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vals.length;i++){
    if(vals[i][1] && vals[i][1].length!=0) {
      ss.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(ss.getRange(i+1,2).getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This still deleted the formula from cells beneath the dataset.

I have set up a sample dataset.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LA4_NeNYjT5-LtfcuNL7ssSvScHEaFAa98-QKv88jco/edit#gid=0

In this, I would want to fix the calcs in B1:B13, but leave the formulas in B14:B.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to spreadsheet of of this site.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any ideas based on the written explanation. All cells in column B has the formula =IF(A1="","",SUM(1+1)) in the case of cell B1. A1:A13 contains data so B1:B13 has the result 2. What I want to achieve is for the result '2' to be fixed to B1:B13, but for the formula in B14:B to remain. Any ideas?